# How to get rid of margin positioning?

Tags: c#, wpf

I just have a general question regarding an issue that I am facing with element scaling/positioning in wpf. Beacuse I am new in wpf, I simply dragged and rescaled elements in visual preview of the application. Of course, this has set the margin to each element, and now when I resize the main window or run the app in full screen mode, everything gets messed up and overlapped. I understand now what the margin does and that it is very static. What is the best way to change this into some dynamic positioning (grid rows/columns). I just have no idea right now.

Comment: Use containers instead, such as Grid or StackPanel. What are you trying to accomplish? At the moment this question is a bit too broad.

Comment: I have the app running in some fixed window size. I want to have it in fullscreen without any deformation of element. Each element is right now like this: <Button Name ="Btn_Import" Margin="19,260,858,330"  Click="Btn_Import_Click" MouseEnter="import_desc" MouseLeave="desc_clear"  >. I just want to take that Margin thing out and then have the button rescale  and reposition appropriately as its parent (main window) increases

Comment: Then you should use a grid with a *-height and width, and use HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" on your components

Comment: Thanks. I am really lost how to do this lol. Can you pls give me sample code where we create a grid 4x4 and then place the button in second row second column of the grid.

Comment: To understand layouts in WPF, you need to know the concept of `Panel`. The Grid is just one of them, but there are more with different behaviors that can be useful in a variety of situations. Take a look at these WPF tutorials to learn more: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/introduction-to-wpf-panels/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to place a button in the second row and second column in a grid, you can use the following XAML code.

Worth noting in the example is that the `*`-definition is relative to other `*`-sizes, so a `1*` is half the size of a `2*` and so on.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" /> <!-- Make this row double in height -->
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" /> <!-- You don't need a number either -->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" /> <!-- All columns are the same size -->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="Hello" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Just adding some more hints... You can define as many Rows and Columns as you want, and if you don't define them then it is implied that at least one Column and/or Row of `Auto` Height and Width exist. Also, if you don't specify `Grid.Row` or `Grid.Column` for some control inside a Grid, then it is positioned by default in the first Row and first Column.

Comment: Thank you. Just one more question. Is it possible to place the button take more than one cell in a grid, for instance 2.2, 2.3, 3.2 and 3.3? Or in other words, to merge four adjacent cells into one bigger cell?

Comment: Yes, you can use the `Grid.RowSpan`, and `Grid.ColumnSpan` properties on each element

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Grid

In a grid, you can define row's height, column's width ... it looks like this

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

You should have a look at [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514525(v=vs.90).aspx)